# flow type dismiss warning of `Experimental decorator usage`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I use [`autobind-decorator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator) `bind` context to `this`.

But I got warning / error `Experimental decorator usage (Decorators are an early stage proposal that may change)`

[image]

How can I dismiss this warning?

Comment: try to add this to your .babelrc file: `{
"presets": ["react-native"], "plugins": ["transform-function-bind", "transform-decorators-legacy"]
}`

Comment: @Cherniv the config you provide makes decorator works with react-native@0.46. thanks =) but the warning still exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `esproposal.decorators=ignore` under the `[options]` section of your `.flowconfig` file. Note that Flow will not understand any type implications of your added decorators, it will simply ignore them.

[Here is the explanation for this flag in the Flow documentation.](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-esproposal-decorators-ignore-warn)